# Default Article content position div in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I wish to show a Article's content on a Joomla template 2.5 page.

I have seen the use of the div ids 'wrapper' with another div 'main' inside that in the index.php page but that seems not to work.

Does normal article content require positions like modules? In the CMS I don't see anything in the Article Manager that allows me to specify a position?

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The articles are showed by default (or any other component content)where this tag is located in your template:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Normal content does not require any position like modules.

Comment: Thanks mate works a treat! Now to switch off all fluff in the CMS!

Comment: great I just needed to conditional the homepage to stop it display non custom module content there and bingo!